# Equivalente ao operador condicional ou ternário no Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Abaixo estou logando no monitor do Android Studio em JAVA uma curta frase usando [operador condicional ou ternário](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html) (?)<sup>en</sup>. Vejam:

```
Log.wtf(GOT, (valirianSteel == 0 && glassOfDragon==0)  ? "Run!" : "Run too!");
```

O que seria equivalente ao operador condicional ou ternário no Kotlin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kotlin não possui operador ternário mas um `if` pode retornar um valor (ou seja é tratado como uma expressão) e funcionar da mesma maneira, com o **detalhe** é você é obrigado a ter um bloco `else`. Como consta na [documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression):

> In Kotlin, if is an expression, i.e. it returns a value. Therefore there is no ternary operator (condition ? then : else), because ordinary if works fine in this role.

Caso o algum dos blocos tenha mais de uma instrução a última será considerada o retorno.

Answer (score 8):

Não existe expressões ternárias propriamente ditas em Kotlin (até a versão tual).

Creio que o mais próximo do ternário em Kotlin seria isso:

```
val max = if (a > b) a else b
```

Existem também outras  implementações descritas [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336500) do SOEN.

Answer (score 7):

Em Kotlin se usa essas estruturas como expressões tb:

```
Log.wtf(GOT, if(valirianSteel == 0 && glassOfDragon==0) "Run!" else "Run too!");
```

Answer (score 7):

Apenas para complementar, na versão 1.1 surgiu a extensão `takeIf`, que junto com o elvis operator (`?:`) pode contribuir nesse caso.

Sua expressão ficaria:

```
Log.wtf(GOT, "Run!".takeIf { valirianSteel == 0 && glassOfDragon==0 } ?: "Run too!")
```

É um pouco diferente do habitual caso esteja cansado do if/else padrão.